# Approved Actions do not hit Newsfeed only (Subset) Activity Log

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, action

I have created and had approved a number of actions. I have requested from the users the Publish_Action permission. This all works well. I have a number of systems that trigger these actions when the user updates stuff on the website. These also trigger and seem to work fine. What I and my users have found is that our namespace/app name has created a new listing in Timeline Activity - So first you have to change the timeline view to see the updates - OK sort of, the updates appear fine in the Activity log, however NONE of the updates ever seem to hit the newsfeed - I think they did when the app had Publish_Stream but now under Publish_Action it does not seem to work.

I have also found that one of my apps is not visible to anyone other than dev,admins etc even thought it has approved actions?

Has anyone else seen these - is there a cure? The code that does the job would have to be correct as the activities and (subset) timelines seem to show the data it is just the main timeline and the newsfeed that do not seem to work?

PS: It does seem to publish to the timeline and newsfeeds if I add a &message - ie: status update with the action but to force one of these would be against guidelines would it not? However the action is generated by the user so is it OK to add a message in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> I have also found that one of my apps is not visible to anyone other than dev,admins etc even thought it has approved actions?

Isn't your app is set to sandbox mode?
You might want to visit the page below and check "Sandbox Mode" option.
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/advanced

Answer (score 0):

> NONE of the updates ever seem to hit the newsfeed - I think they did when the app had Publish_Stream but now under Publish_Action it does not seem to work.

To start with, [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/) might help you understand the latest version of publish_stream and publish_actions permission.
According to [the document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/#social-channels), it is not guaranteed that all actions to be published on news feed since it is affected by the EdgeRank. It's my guess, but if your app is publishing so many actions, the priority of each action would be lower and so as EdgeRank.